# Large, persistent DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am exploring switching to python and pandas as a long-time SAS user.

However, when running some tests today, I was surprised that python ran out of memory when trying to `pandas.read_csv()` a 128mb csv file.  It had about 200,000 rows and 200 columns of mostly numeric data.

With SAS, I can import a csv file into a SAS dataset and it can be as large as my hard drive.

Is there something analogous in `pandas`?

I regularly work with large files and do not have access to a distributed computing network.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas, but you might want to look through iterating through the file.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In principle it shouldn't run out of memory, but there are currently memory problems with `read_csv` on large files caused by some complex Python internal issues (this is vague but it's been known for a long time: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/407).

At the moment there isn't a perfect solution (here's a tedious one: you could transcribe the file row-by-row into a pre-allocated NumPy array or memory-mapped file--`np.mmap`), but it's one I'll be working on in the near future. Another solution is to read the file in smaller pieces (use `iterator=True, chunksize=1000`) then concatenate then with `pd.concat`. The problem comes in when you pull the entire text file into memory in one big slurp.

Comment: Say I can read the file and concat all of them together into one DataFrame.  Does the DataFrame have to reside in memory?  With SAS, I can work with datasets of any size as long as I have the hard-drive space.  Is it the same with DataFrames?  I get the impression they are constrained by RAM and not hard-drive space.  Sorry for the noob question and thanks for you help. I'm enjoying your book.

Comment: Right, you're constrained by RAM. SAS indeed has much better support for "out-of-core" big data processing.

Comment: @WesMcKinney These workarounds shouldn't be needed any longer, because of the new csv loader you landed in 0.10, right?

Answer (score 89):

Wes is of course right! I'm just chiming in to provide a little more complete example code. I had the same issue with a 129 Mb file, which was solved by:

```
import pandas as pd
    
# Returns a TextFileReader, which is iterable with chunks of 1000 rows.
csv_iterator = pd.read_csv('large_dataset.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
# Iterate through the dataframe chunks and print one row/record at a time
for chunk in csv_iterator:
    for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
        print(row)

# df is DataFrame. If errors, use `list(csv_iterator)` instead
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I think you can just do `df = concate(tp, ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: @smci Tried this quickly with the same data repeated x4 (550 Mb) or x8 (1.1Gb). Interestingly, with or without [x for x in tp], the x4 went through fine, and x8 crashed in a MemoryError.

Comment: @fickludd Are you using ipython / is the dataframe is persisting in memory rather than being garbage collected?

Comment: @AndyHayden Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2. How could the data be garbage collected - I still have it stored in a dataframe?

Comment: @fickludd Sorry not sure I understand the issue then :)

Comment: I get this error while using it:
`AssertionError: first argument must be a list-like of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "TextFileReader"`.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: This bug will be fixed in 0.14 (release soon), https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6941; workaround for < 0.14.0 is to do ``pd.concat(list(tp), ignore_index=True)``

Comment: what if the values are strings or categorical - i am getting the error: incompatible categories in categorical concat

Comment: This was really really helpful. Thanks. Was stuck on it for quite some time.

Comment: why does `ignore_index` need to be true?

Comment: HI .. May also request for a solution for a similar problem that I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490474/memory-error-performing-sentiment-analysis-large-size-data

Answer (score 45):

This is an older thread, but I just wanted to dump my workaround solution here. I initially tried the `chunksize` parameter (even with quite small values like 10000), but it didn't help much; had still technical issues with the memory size (my CSV was ~ 7.5 Gb).

Right now, I just read chunks of the CSV files in a for-loop approach and add them e.g., to an SQLite database step by step:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql
import subprocess

# In and output file paths
in_csv = '../data/my_large.csv'
out_sqlite = '../data/my.sqlite'

table_name = 'my_table' # name for the SQLite database table
chunksize = 100000 # number of lines to process at each iteration

# columns that should be read from the CSV file
columns = ['molecule_id','charge','db','drugsnow','hba','hbd','loc','nrb','smiles']

# Get number of lines in the CSV file
nlines = subprocess.check_output('wc -l %s' % in_csv, shell=True)
nlines = int(nlines.split()[0]) 

# connect to database
cnx = sqlite3.connect(out_sqlite)

# Iteratively read CSV and dump lines into the SQLite table
for i in range(0, nlines, chunksize):

    df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,  
            header=None,  # no header, define column header manually later
            nrows=chunksize, # number of rows to read at each iteration
            skiprows=i)   # skip rows that were already read

    # columns to read        
    df.columns = columns

    sql.to_sql(df, 
                name=table_name, 
                con=cnx, 
                index=False, # don't use CSV file index
                index_label='molecule_id', # use a unique column from DataFrame as index
                if_exists='append') 
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Super useful to see a realistic use-case for the chunked reading feature.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a small remark, to this old topic: `pandas.read_csv` directly returns (at least on the version I'm currently using) an iterator if you simply provide `iterator=True` and `chunksize=chunksize`. Hence, you would just do a `for` loop over the `pd.read_csv` call, instead of re-instantiating it every time. However, this costs only the call overhead, there maybe no significant impact.

Comment: Hi, Joel. Thanks for the note! The `iterator=True` and `chunksize` parameters already existed back then if I remember correctly. Maybe there was a bug in an older version which caused the memory blow-up -- I will give it another try next time I read a large DataFrame in Pandas (I am mostly using Blaze now for such tasks)

Answer (score 6):

Below is my working flow.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

count = 0
con = sa.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pwd@localhost:00001/r')
#con = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///XXXXX.db') SQLite
chunks = pd.read_csv('..file', chunksize=10000, encoding="ISO-8859-1",
                     sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
```

Base on your file size, you'd better optimized the chunksize.

```
 for chunk in chunks:
        chunk.to_sql(name='Table', if_exists='append', con=con)
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

After have all data in Database, You can query out those you need from database.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load huge csv files, dask might be a good option. It mimics the pandas api, so it feels quite similar to pandas

[link to dask on github](https://github.com/dask)

Comment: Thanks, since I posted this I've been using dask and the parquet format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pytable rather than pandas df.
It is designed for large data sets and the file format is in hdf5.
So the processing time is relatively fast.