# Loading big CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to load a csv file (around 250 MB) as dataframe with pandas. In my first try I used the typical read_csv command but I receive an Error memory.
I have tried the approach mentioned in [Large, persistent DataFrame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas) using chunks:

```
x=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
xx=pd.concat([chunk for chunk in x], ignore_index=True)
```

but when I tried to concatenate I received the following **error: Exception: "All objects passed were None"**. In fact I can not access the chunks

I am using winpython 3.3.2.1 for 32 bits with pandas 0.11.0

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Did you upgrade to pandas 0.12.0?

Comment: Yes, I install last winpython 64 bits version and it worked withmy files. I still have to tested with bigger files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you install the 64 Bit version of winpython. Then you should be able to load a 250 MB file without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but the actual problem with the posted code is that using `pd.concat([chunk for chunk in x])` effectively cancels any benefit of chunking because it concatenates all those chunks into one big DataFrame again.
That probably even requires twice the memory temporarily.