# Python pandas read_sql returns generator object

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am pulling data from Oracle db using pyodbc and pandas read_sql.

I see no errors when I enter this line

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_str,cnxn,chunksize=10)
```

But when I try to see

```
df
```

I get this error

```
<generator object _query_iterator at 0x092D40F8>
```

My search as to what this error means or what could be causing it yielded no satisfactory answers.

The reason for using chunksize is that I have a Oracle db table with 60 million rows, and plan to download in bits and then put them together, just like here: 
[How to create a large pandas dataframe from an sql query without running out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of)

Comment: To be specific, what you see is not an 'error', it says the the `df` object is a generator object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the explanation of `chunksize` says, when specified, it *returns an iterator where chunksize is the number of rows to include in each chunk*.
So you can iterate through the result and do something with each chunk:

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql_str, engine, chunksize=10):
    do_something_with(chunk)
```

Typically you can process the chunk and add it to a list, and then after this for loop concat all processed chunks in this list together.

Also see the docs on sql querying: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#querying for an example.

Comment: How to add all of them together in one dataframe?

Comment: You can use `pd.concat(list(chunks))` for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to comment but cannot yet. Regardless, that is not an error that is telling you that `df` is a generator object.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that the error is uninformative?

Comment: As the other answers indicate you can loop over the generator object to get specific data points.