# pandas read_sql not reading all rows

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I am running the exact same query both through pandas' read_sql and through an external app (DbVisualizer).

DbVisualizer returns 206 rows, while pandas returns 178.

I have tried reading the data from pandas by chucks based on the information provided at [How to create a large pandas dataframe from an sql query without running out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of), it didn't make a change.

What could be the cause for this and ways to remedy it?

The query:

```
select *
from rainy_days
where year=’2010’ and day=‘weekend’
```

The columns contain: date, year, weekday, amount of rain at that day, temperature, geo_location (row per location), wind measurements, amount of rain the day before, etc..

The exact python code (minus connection details) is:

```
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(
   'postgresql://user:pass@server.com/weatherhist?port=5439',
)

query = """
        select *
        from rainy_days
        where year=’2010’ and day=‘weekend’
        """
df = pandas.read_sql(query, con=engine)
```

Comment: You are using strange quotes (for the `year=’2010’`), I don't know if that could be a cause, but can you replace them with normal single quotes? (`'`)

Comment: is there a solution to this?  I'm running the same issue.

Comment: same issue. I have a table with total 7 rows, pandas.read_sql_table get 7 but pandas.read_sql get 5 rows.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a fix, but what worked for me was to rebuild the indices:

1. drop the indices
2. export the whole thing to a csv:
3. delete all the rows:

   DELETE FROM table
4. import the csv back in
5. rebuild the indices

pandas:

```
df = read_csv(..)
df.to_sql(..)
```

If that works, then at least you know you have a problem somewhere with the indices keeping up to date.

Comment: the strange quotes `` are used in SQL to distinguish field names from reserved words, e.g. SELECT \`right\` FROM ...

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/xzkostyan/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/issues/14

If you use pure engine.execute you should care about format manually

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that pandas returns a *packed* dataframe (DF). For some reason this is always on by default and the results varies widely as to what is shown. The solution is to use the *unpacking* operator (**`*`**) before/when trying to print the *df*, like this:

```py
print(*df)
```

(This is also know as the *splat* operator for Ruby enthusiasts.)

To read more about this, please check out these references & tutorials:

- https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-star-or-asterisk-operator/
- https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558
- https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480