# pandas.read_sql not returning all records

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a complex query that I'm running against a SQL Server database. When I run that query in SSMS, it returns 15,652 rows.

However, when I use that query in my python it only returns 10,617 records. This only started happening recently.

This is how I'm executing the query in python:

```
driver = 'Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=yes;'.format(server,database)
params = parse.quote_plus(driver)
db_engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, fast_executemany=True)

df = pandas.read_sql(qry, db_engine)
```

I can't figure out what is limiting the number of records coming back. I've tried using the `chucksize` parameter on `pandas.read_sql` but still get the same incorrect number of records back. I've also tried removing `fast_executemany=True` from the engine creation but no luck.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this is a common pandas issue and the solutions may not be much useful. Have you already taken a look at [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841600/pandas-read-sql-not-reading-all-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My code was pointing to an old version of the query. It's working fine.