# SQL iterate over distinct values of a column and build a data frame for each value

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
|A|B|C|D|
|---|---|---|---|
|1|b1|c1|d1|
|1|b2|c2|d2|
|2|b3|c3|d3|
|2|b4|c4|d4|
```

I would like to iterate over distinct values of A and build a pandas data frame out of the remaining columns and then use that table to do calculations.  I tried the following:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
conn = sqlite3.connection('my_db.db')
c = conn.cursor()
for entry in c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT A in table):
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE A = ?", (entry[0],)).fetchall())
```

This doesn't work because the second cursor object that builds the dataframe overwrites the cursor object that i was iterating over.  I also discovered that you can not have two cursor objects.  How should I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end solution was to use `pandas.read_sql` with `chunksize`

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of) useful as well.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
conn = sqlite3.connection('my_db.db')
for df in pd.read_sql("SELECT * from table ORDER BY A ASC", conn, chunksize = 100000):
    group  = df.groupby('A')
    last   = group.first().tail(1).index.values[0]
    last_a = 0
    for a, g_df in group:
        if (a == last_a):
            g_df = l_df.append(g_df)

        ....calculations....

        if (a == last):
            l_df = g_df
            l_a  = a
```

It is really important to have logic that ties together the groupby data frames that are split into two different chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to do this whole operation in pandas itself? You could simply do it like so:

```
parent_df = pd.read_sql(c, "SELECT * from table")
for name, group in parent_df.groupby('A'):
    print(name, group.head())
```

Or

```
parent_df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
parent_df.head(20)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not read the whole table into memory at once so I can't use pandas in that fashion.  Good to know that is an option though!

Comment: `pandas.read_sql` has `chunksize` kwag. Sort your table using SQL query, then use the `chunksize` option.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the data you're interested in into a DataFrame (if it's not a huge dataset) then filter the dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(c.execute("SELECT * FROM table").fetchall())
distict_a = df['A'].unique()
for a in distinct_a:
    df_for_this_a = df.query[df.A == a]
```

Comment: This works but part of the challenge is I can not load the entire table into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using pandas's [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) (with parameterization in passing the cursor value) and iteratively save each dataframe to a dictionary where the reference key is the corresponding distinct value (dict route avoids multiple dfs in your global environment):

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
c = conn.cursor()

dfDict = {}
for entry in c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT A FROM table"):
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE A = :nameofparam"   
    dfDict[entry[0]] = pd.read_sql(strSQL, conn, params={'nameofparam': entry[0]})

c.close()
conn.close()

for k, v in dfDict.items():
    print(k, '\n', v.head())
```

Comment: I know that for regular SQL queries it is important to use "?"  to protect against sql attacks.  Is the code above safe?  Can pd.read_sql() execute code?

Comment: See update using the params arg of `read_sql` which passes the cursor value to a named parameter binded to sql statement. This protects against sql injection.