# For loop to run till a number in order to avoid MemoryError in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, while-loop, pyodbc

I'm extracting JSON data object from sql table processing it to extract data from it and putting it back in same table

```
R_GEOCODE_ID   JSON            Street_Numb   Street_Name   Route   sublocality   Country   ...
12  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
40  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
30  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
```

In above table the actual JSON data could not be accumulated so I'm pasting it separately below
JSON

```
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"16","short_name":"16","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Bhagwan Tatyasaheb Kawade Road","short_name":"BT Kawde Road","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Palmgrove Society","short_name":"Palmgrove Society","types":["neighborhood","political"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"16, BT Kawade Road, Palmgrove Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.5132611,"lng":73.907346},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5146100802915,"lng":73.90869498029151},"southwest":{"lat":18.51191211970849,"lng":73.90599701970851}}},"place_id":"ChIJo1QsU7nBwjsRiewRdiNc2i4","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.510892,"lng":73.906956},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5122409802915,"lng":73.9083049802915},"southwest":{"lat":18.5095430197085,"lng":73.90560701970848}}},"place_id":"ChIJ5YdfqcDBwjsR5VJutWLCsfA","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]}],"status":"OK"}
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

So for those column in table whose values are **NA** I wanted them to fill up by extracting the JSON objects from each records.

this is the code to extract the data

```
    import pyodbc
                import json
                import numpy as np
                import pandas as pd
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=temp;UID=ADMIN;PWD=abc@123;autocommit=True')
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("select TOP 10000 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")


               ID=[]
            json_string=[]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
 ID.append(row[0]) 
 json_string.append(row[1])

address_fields = {
'intersection': [],        
'political': [],        
'country': [],        
'administrative_area_level_1': [],        
'administrative_area_level_2': [],        
'administrative_area_level_3': [],        
'administrative_area_level_4': [],        
'administrative_area_level_5': [],        
'colloquial_area': [],
'locality': [],
'ward': [],
'neighborhood': [],
'premise': [],
'subpremise': [],
'natural_feature': [],
'postal_code': [],       
'airport': [],
'park': [],                
'point_of_interest': [],
'street_address': [],                     
'street_number': [],
'route': [],
'sublocality': [],
}
dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)
json_all = json.loads(dumpData)

#print(json_all)
#json_all = json.loads(json_string)

id_index = 0
for json_str in json_all:
     address_fields = {
      'intersection': [],        
      'political': [],        
      'country': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_1': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_2': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_3': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_4': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_5': [],        
      'colloquial_area': [],
      'locality': [],
      'ward': [],
      'neighborhood': [],
      'premise': [],
      'subpremise': [],
      'natural_feature': [],
      'postal_code': [],       
      'airport': [],
      'park': [],                
      'point_of_interest': [],
      'street_address': [],        
      'street_number': [],
      'route': [],
      'sublocality': [],
     }
     json_results = json.loads(json_str)
     if not json_results or not json_results[0].get('address_components'):
          id_index = id_index + 1
          continue 
     first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
     for item in first_address_components:
         for field_key in address_fields.keys():
            if field_key in item['types']:
               address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])

     # convert lists to single strings
     address_fields = {key: ', '.join(values) for key, values in address_fields.items()}
     sql = "UPDATE MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE SET intersection=?, political=?, country=?, administrative_area_level_1=?, administrative_area_level_2=?, administrative_area_level_3=?, administrative_area_level_4=?, administrative_area_level_5=?, colloquial_area=?, locality=?, ward=?, neighborhood=?, premise=?, subpremise=?, postal_code=?, natural_feature=?, airport=?, park=?, point_of_interest=?, street_address=?, Street_Number=?, Route=?, sublocality=? WHERE R_GEOCODE_ID=?"
     params = (
        address_fields['intersection'],     
        address_fields['political'],     
        address_fields['country'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_1'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_2'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_3'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_4'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_5'],     
        address_fields['colloquial_area'],     
        address_fields['locality'],     
        address_fields['ward'],     
        address_fields['neighborhood'],     
        address_fields['premise'],     
        address_fields['subpremise'],  
        address_fields['postal_code'],              
        address_fields['natural_feature'],          
        address_fields['airport'],     
        address_fields['park'],     
        address_fields['point_of_interest'],     
        address_fields['street_address'],     
        address_fields['street_number'],
        address_fields['route'],
        address_fields['sublocality'],
        ID[id_index]
     )
     cursor.execute(sql, params)
     id_index = id_index + 1


cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

This condition `select  ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")` returns about 315200 rows satisfying the condition.
So when I try to run the entire code for all these 315200 rows it gives me ERROR `MemoryError`
So I have to do `select TOP 100 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")`
So as to run properly, so I m trying to run a loop till 315200

```
for i in range(315200):
cursor.execute("select TOP 10000 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")


           ID=[]
        json_string=[]
#Process JSON data
.
.
#code for Updating the sql columns back in table
```

.
.

But Not sure if that's a right way to do , or else there could be much efficient way to do this.
Any suggestions would be appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried chunking in the manner answered here in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108357/5189811

Comment: You didn't post the most important part: your effective code. If you're doing a `cursor.fetchall()`, store all your processed data in memory etc then no suprise you fill up your memory...

Comment: Refreshed the post with updated answer

Comment: Can you show how you're looping through the results from the `cursor.execute` with proper indentation?