# Select a certain range of rows to create a db

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, row

I am using the sqlalchemy module to import a .sqlite3 sheet and create an engine to form a database.

The number of rows in my sql file is far more than I require - how  do I format the range of rows that are selected to go into the database? For example, the first 10000 rows of a 100000 row file are to be imported only.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import os


    db_dir = os.path.join("file_path_found_here", 'sqlfile.sqlite3')
database_url = f'sqlite:///{db_dir}'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_url)
if os.path.isfile(db_dir):
    df = pd.read_sql('FSC_Data', engine, index_col=['time'])
    print(df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a large pandas dataframe from an sql query without running out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pandas.read_sql_query(...)` method instead of `read_sql(...)`

You could try something like:

```
myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10000'
if os.path.isfile(db_dir):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(myQuery, engine, index_col=['time'])
    print(df)
```