# Pandas: how to work with really big data?

Tags: python, pandas

My sample of data is really big (1.2 million documents), and I need to create and analyse data on only one "pandas dataframe". For now my code looks like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor('aggre')
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_ob_indicators;")
row = cur.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(row,columns = ['timestamp', 'topAsk', 'topBid', 'CPA', 'midprice', 'CPB', 'spread', 'CPA%', 'CPB%'])
```

But it will take ages to localy upload everything in the variable df? What I tried so far was to do this:

```
for row in cur:
      dfsub = pd.DataFrame(row,columns=['timestamp', 'topAsk', 'topBid', 'CPA', 'midprice', 'CPB', 'spread', 'CPA%', 'CPB%'])
      df = df.concat([df,dfsub])
```

but it gives me the following error: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of

Comment: Even if your snippet worked, `df.concat([df,dfsub])` would be extremely expensive. It reallocates the whole df on every iteration.

Comment: look into this: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has a nice builtin [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) method that should be pretty efficient

i.e. just do:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_ob_indicators", conn)
```

and it should just work…

on its own 1.2 million rows isn't much, given your column count/names it's probably <300MB of RAM (30 bytes per value * 9 columns * 1.2e6 rows) and should take <10 seconds on a recent computer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
class Postgres:
def __init__(self, host, database, user=None, password='', schema='public'):
    self.user = user or getpass.getuser()
    self.database = database
    self.host = host
    self.engine = self.create_engine(self.host, self.database, self.user, password)
    self.schema = schema

@staticmethod
def create_engine(host, database, user, password):
    return psycopg2.connect("postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}".format(
        host=host,
        database=database,
        user=user,
        password=password
    ))

def execute(self, query: object) -> object:
    """
    :param query:
    :return: pd.Dataframe()
    """
    result_df = pd.read_sql(query, self.engine)
    self.engine.commit()
    return result_df
```

with this you use the optimized DataFrame creation from a postgres result of pandas.

But reasoned by your dataset it takes some time to read all the data into memory

Answer (score -1):

I think that since your document set is so large, it will take a long time to load it into memory no matter how you go about it. I would suggest, if you do not need to hold the entire dataset in memory at once, you could use the pandas inbuilt load chunk method. This allows you to sequentially load and process chunks of your data designed for this use case.

See this question for example
[How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)