# Python pandas read_sql_query fails without report or exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have previously used pandas to read smaller tables < 1 million rows.
I attempted to read a very large table and my python script fails.
I tried to catch an exception but I got no message.
I then tried to run the script as very basic and I go an error but no message.

```
  Message=
  Source=R:\0400_GIM\Working\0010_Python_Scripts_PRODVM\ACQ_Pivot\TestGeophysDetails.py
  StackTrace:
  File "R:\0400_GIM\Working\0010_Python_Scripts_PRODVM\ACQ_Pivot\TestGeophysDetails.py", line 60, in <module>
    dfHBC = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [ACQ_RH_EXP].[dbo].[GEOPHYSDETAILS]', acqEngine)
```

How do I determine if the error is a timeout or something else?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, That works for reading the data.
I would still like to know why I am not receiving an error or timeout on the original query.