# DRF Pagination custom response without model APIView

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

Hello I have a project in Django, which performs several queries to different databases returning them in several endpoints, for this I use Pandas and DRF (APIViews).

The problem arises when the response is very long and logically the server runs out of memory, I understand that I need to paginate the result but I have not found the way to do it because I do not use models or serializers, I do raw queries with pandas to make the queries.

Is there any way to paginate the results the way I'm doing it?

I leave some snippets of my code.

```
class AffiliateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)  
    def get(self, request):
        insurance = self.request.query_params.get('insurance', None)
        emergensys_df = pd.read_sql_query(general_attention(insurance), engine())
        return Response(emergensys_df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18107953/6759844) might help

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a streaming response. Django has `StreamingHttpResponse` for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects
Basically, you should do the following:

- create a generator, that gets the data from the database by chuncks using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` SQL operators, processes it, and returns by chunks either.
- create and return `StreamingHttpResponse` and pass the generator into it like: `return StreamingHttpResponse(your_generator)`