# How to force a python function to return a particular type of object?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I am using pandas to read a csv file and convert it into a numpy array. Earlier I was loading the whole file and was getting memory error. So I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas/12193309#12193309) link and tried to read the file in chunks.

But now I am getting a different error which say:
`AssertionError: first argument must be a list-like of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "TextFileReader"`

This is the code I am using:

```
>>> X_chunks = pd.read_csv('train_v2.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
>>> X = pd.concat(X_chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

[API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) for read_csv tells that it returns either a DataFrame or a TextParser. The problem is that concat function will work fine if X_chunks is DataFrame, but its type is TextParser here.

is there any way in which I can force the return type for read_csv or any work around to load the whole file as a numpy array?

Comment: Their is a very clear example in the docs, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk. The point of the iteration/chunking is to DO something with generated frames. Simply concating will not solve your memory problem. For example, you could write to an HDF5 file; eliminate some columns and write to a new csv, or process the chunks and summarize.

Comment: Yeah, what Jeff said.

Answer (score 1):

Since `iterator=False` is the default, and `chunksize` forces a `TextFileReader` object, may I suggest:

```
X_chunks = pd.read_csv('train_v2.csv')
```

But you don't want to materialize the list?

Final suggestion:

```
X_chunks = pd.read_csv('train_v2.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
for chunk in x_chunks:
    analyze(chunk)
```

Where `analyze` is whatever process you've broken up to analyze the chunks piece by piece, since you apparently can't load the entire dataset into memory.

You can't use concat in the way you're trying to, the reason is that it demands the data be fully materialized, which makes sense, **you can't concatenate something that isn't there yet.**

Comment: Edited, please review!

Comment: This will cause memory problem. I was using reading the file in chunks to avoid it.

Comment: Final analysis, sorry!