# Python, Memory Error in making dataframe

Tags: python, memory, pandas

When I use pandas DataFrame, occuring the **Memory Error**.

data's row is 200000 and column is 30.(type: list)
fieldnames1 has columns name.(type:list)

Error occured in:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=[fieldnames1])
```

what should I do?
(python version 2.7 32bit)

Comment: You ran out of RAM. Try to use less data for testing and a combination of more RAM, a 64bit OS and 64bit Python.

Comment: Any reason you don't use 64-bit version of python? Also storing lists in a df is a bit strange

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Klaus, you're running out of memory. The problem occurs when you try to pull the entire text to memory in one go.

As pointed out [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas) by Wes McKinney, "a solution is to read the file in smaller pieces (use `iterator=True, chunksize=1000`) then concatenate then with pd.concat".

Answer (score -1):

You can try this line of code:

```
data=pd.DataFrame.from_csv("train.csv")
```

This is an alternate of read.csv but it returns Data frame object without giving any memory error
P.S the size of the training data is around 73 mb