# Find a string in a huge string file

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas

I have to find a list of strings in a txt.file

The file has 200k+ lines

**This is my code:**

```
with open(txtfile, 'rU') as csvfile:
    tp = pd.read_csv(csvfile, iterator=True, chunksize=6000, error_bad_lines=False,
                     header=None, skip_blank_lines=True, lineterminator="\n")
    for chunk in tp:
        if string_to_find in chunk:
            print "hurrà"
```

**The problem** is that with this code only the first 9k lines are analyzed.
Why?

Comment: hope this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622652/large-persistent-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for chunk in pd.read_csv(csvfile, iterator=True, chunksize=6000, error_bad_lines=False,
                     header=None, skip_blank_lines=True, lineterminator="\n"):`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to open the file first then use pandas? If it's an option you can just read with pandas then [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

To do that just use `read_csv`, `concat` the files, then loop through them.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=6000, error_bad_lines=False,
                 header=None, skip_blank_lines=True)
df = pd.concat(df)

# start the for loop
```

It depends on your for loop, `pandas` most likely will have a function that you won't need to loop as it's slower to process large data.