# Progress bar for pandas.DataFrame.to_sql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, dataframe, tqdm

I want to migrate data from a large csv file to sqlite3 database.

My code on Python 3.5 using pandas:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILENAME)
df = pd.read_csv(MLS_FULLPATH)
df.to_sql(con=con, name="MLS", if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Is it possible to print current status (progress bar) of execution of to_sql method?

I looked the article about [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), but didn't find how to do this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortuantely `DataFrame.to_sql` does not provide a chunk-by-chunk callback, which is needed by tqdm to update its status. However, you can process the dataframe chunk by chunk:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

DB_FILENAME='/tmp/test.sqlite'

def chunker(seq, size):
    # from http://stackoverflow.com/a/434328
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

def insert_with_progress(df, dbfile):
    con = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
    chunksize = int(len(df) / 10) # 10%
    with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
        for i, cdf in enumerate(chunker(df, chunksize)):
            replace = "replace" if i == 0 else "append"
            cdf.to_sql(con=con, name="MLS", if_exists=replace, index=False)
            pbar.update(chunksize)
            
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,100000)})
insert_with_progress(df, DB_FILENAME)
```

Note I'm generating the DataFrame inline here for the sake of having a complete workable example without dependency.

The result is quite stunning:

[image]

Comment: my csv file takes 1.7 GB place on the disk, so df=pd.read_csv(csv_filename, ...) works very slow. But I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28371706/5856795, so your answer and answer @sebastian-raschka help me to do this task.

Comment: With range() in stead of xrange() this also works in Python 3.
Very nicely, I must say!

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to share a variant of the solution posted by miraculixx - that I had to alter for SQLAlchemy:

```
#these need to be customized - myDataFrame, myDBEngine, myDBTable

df=myDataFrame

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

def insert_with_progress(df):
    con = myDBEngine.connect()
    chunksize = int(len(df) / 10)
    with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
        for i, cdf in enumerate(chunker(df, chunksize)):
            replace = "replace" if i == 0 else "append"
            cdf.to_sql(name="myDBTable", con=conn, if_exists=replace, index=False) 
            pbar.update(chunksize)
            tqdm._instances.clear()

insert_with_progress(df)
```

Comment: You defined the variable `replace` but don't use it. Did you mean `if_exists=replace`?

Answer (score 0):

User miraculixx has a nice example above, thank you for that. But if you want to use it with files of all sizes you should add something like this:

```
chunksize = int(len(df) / 10)
if chunksize == 0:
    df.to_sql(con=con, name="MLS", if_exists="replace", index=False)
else:
    with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
    ...
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could finish the example you posted above? When I set the integer in the `chunksize` variable, I only get that amount into my db. e.g., `chunksize = int(len(df) / 10)` then only 1/10 of the total records are being recorded into my db.