# How to print a message every time a chunksize is written to the database in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@server/db')
df.to_sql('new_table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=20000)
```

I want to print a message every time a chunksize has to been written to the DB, so that I know the script is successfully running. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always chunk it up manually and process chunks in a loop inside which you can setup message printing or a progress bar. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495229/11477031).